# INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.server.HSAd minServer failed in state INITED;

Tags: hadoop

```
  for i  don't know why the   Exception from container-launch: ExitCodeException exitCode=1;
```

[root@hadoop-senior hadoop-2.5.0]# bin/yarn jar jsrs/mr-worcount.jar /user/centos/mapreduce/wordcount/input /user/centos/mapreduce/wordcount/output4

17/01/11 04:24:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    17/01/11 04:24:14 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /192.168.85.129:8032
    17/01/11 04:24:15 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
    17/01/11 04:24:15 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
    17/01/11 04:24:15 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    17/01/11 04:24:15 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
    17/01/11 04:24:16 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1484121450974_0004
    17/01/11 04:24:16 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
    17/01/11 04:24:16 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1484121450974_0004
    17/01/11 04:24:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hadoop-senior:8088/proxy/application_1484121450974_0004/
    17/01/11 04:24:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1484121450974_0004
    17/01/11 04:24:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1484121450974_0004 running in uber mode : false
    17/01/11 04:24:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    17/01/11 04:24:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1484121450974_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
    Exception from container-launch: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

```
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

17/01/11 04:24:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1484121450974_0004_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

17/01/11 04:24:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1484121450974_0004_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

17/01/11 04:24:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
17/01/11 04:24:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1484121450974_0004 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1484121450974_0004_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

17/01/11 04:24:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 12
        Job Counters enter code here
                Failed map tasks=4
                Launched map tasks=4
                Other local map tasks=3
                Data-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=4775
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=4775
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=4775
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=4889600
        Map-Reduce Framework
                CPU time spent (ms)=0
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
```

Comment: Please explain the context in which this error was shown, as there is no way of helping you unless you explain it.

Answer (score 0):

```
this is logs
2017-01-09 22:53:40,282 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, H
UP, INT]
2017-01-09 22:53:42,975 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform.
.. using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-01-09 22:53:43,299 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: JobHistory Init
2017-01-09 22:53:43,790 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Waiting for FileSystem at hadoop-senior:80
20to be available
2017-01-09 22:54:13,805 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Waiting for FileSystem at hadoop-senior:80
20to be available
2017-01-09 22:54:43,819 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Waiting for FileSystem at hadoop-senior:80
20to be available
2017-01-09 22:55:13,828 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Waiting for FileSystem at hadoop-senior:80
20to be available
2017-01-09 22:55:43,835 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Waiting for FileSystem at hadoop-senior:80
20to be available
2017-01-09 22:56:13,846 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Waiting for FileSystem at hadoop-senior:80
20to be available
2017-01-09 22:56:43,858 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Waiting for FileSystem at hadoop-senior:80
20to be available
2017-01-09 22:57:13,865 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Waiting for FileSystem at hadoop-senior:80
20to be available
2017-01-09 22:57:44,312 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Initializing Existing Jobs...
2017-01-09 22:57:44,391 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.CachedHistoryStorage: CachedHistoryStorage Init
2017-01-09 22:57:44,429 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockin
gQueue
2017-01-09 22:57:44,446 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.server.HSAd
minServer failed in state INITED; cause: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:10033] java.net.BindException: A
ddress already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:10033] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details s
ee:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:719)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:419)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:897)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:505)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:480)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:742)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.server.HSAdminServer.serviceInit(HSAdminServer.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.serviceInit(JobHistoryServer.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.launchJobHistoryServer(JobHistoryServer.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.main(JobHistoryServer.java:229)
2017-01-09 22:57:44,449 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryS
erver failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding
 to [0.0.0.0:10033] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Bind
Exception
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:10033] java.net.BindExce
ption: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException.convert(ServiceStateException.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.serviceInit(JobHistoryServer.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.launchJobHistoryServer(JobHistoryServer.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.main(JobHistoryServer.java:229)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:10033] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For mor
e details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:719)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:419)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:897)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:505)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:480)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:742)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.server.HSAdminServer.serviceInit(HSAdminServer.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        ... 5 more
2017-01-09 22:57:44,450 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Stopping JobHistory
2017-01-09 22:57:44,451 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer: Error starting JobHistoryServer
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:10033] java.net.BindExce
ption: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException.convert(ServiceStateException.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.serviceInit(JobHistoryServer.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.launchJobHistoryServer(JobHistoryServer.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.main(JobHistoryServer.java:229)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:10033] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For mor
e details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:719)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:419)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:897)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:505)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:480)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:742)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.server.HSAdminServer.serviceInit(HSAdminServer.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        ... 5 more
2017-01-09 22:57:44,456 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status -1
2017-01-09 22:57:44,459 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down JobHistoryServer at hadoop-senior/192.168.85.129
```